# Matrices in discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $A=\{0,1,2,3\}$ and let $R$ and $S$ be the relations on $A$ described by the matrices

$M_R=
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$

$M_S= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

> **Question 1**
>
> Compute $M_{R^{-1}}$, $M_{R \cap S}$, $M_{R \circ S}$.
>
> **Question 2**
>
> Use Warshall's algorithm to compute the transitive closure of $R \cup S$.

Can anyone help me step by step how to deal with these matrices?
Especially Warshall's algorithm, I really don't understand even though studying my lecture notes.

I really need the sample solutions for my later exam.

I know that your answer will be help in my exam. Thanks lot.

Comment: What is this $M$ function? Aren't relations usually subsets of $A\times A$, not matrices? Or is this some sort of convention like $M_{R}(i,j)={\rm if}(A_i\,R\,A_j,1,0)$?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you will need to understand how to interpret these matrices. They are Boolean matrices where entry $M_{ij}=1$ if $(i,j)$ is in the relation and $0$ otherwise. As an example, the relation $R$ is
\begin{align*}
R=\{(0,3),(2,1),(3,2)\}.
\end{align*}

### Question 1

For the inverse relation, try writing the the pairs contained in $R^{-1}$ and represent this in matrix form. How does this matrix relate to $M_R$?

> It's the transposed matrix. We have $(a,b)\in R^{-1}$ if $(b,a)\in R$, which corresponds to transposing the matrix.

The intersection of the relations is defined such that $(a,b)\in R\cap S$ if both $(a,b)\in R$ and $(a,b)\in S$. How does this translate to matrices? Consider the entry $(i,j)$ in $M_{R\cap S}$: When it is $1$, what must be true about the entries $(i,j)$ in $M_R$ and $M_S$?

> Both of the entries must be $1$. Thus, $M_{R\cap S}=0_{4\times 4}$ in this example.

To find the composition, it can be shown that this corresponds to the Boolean product of the matrices.

### Question 2

First, you have to find the matrix $M_{R\cup S}$. In the case of the intersection the entries of both matrices $M_R$ and $M_S$ had to be $1$, since both relations should contain the pair. In the union, only one of the relations need to contain the pair. How does this translate to the matrices?

> Entry $(i,j)$ in $M_{R\cup S}$ is $1$ if entry $(i,j)$ is $1$ in *either* $M_R$ or $M_S$.

For $n\times n$ matrices, Warshall's algorithm consist of $n$ steps. First, we fix $k=1$ and construct a matrix $W$ where $W_{ij}=M_{ij}\vee (M_{ik}\wedge M_{kj})$ (here $M$ denotes the matrix representation of the relation). Consider a small example:

\begin{align*}
M=\left[\begin{array}{c c c}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}

Fix $k=1$. We can transfer the first row and column immediately. Further, all $1$'s can be transferred. For the remaining entries, we check the corresponding entries in the $k$'th row and column -- here marked with a box. If these are both $1$, we write $1$, otherwise $0$.
\begin{align*}
W_1=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & ? & ?
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \boxed{0} & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
\boxed{1} & \mathbf{0} & ?
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & \boxed{0}\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
\boxed{1} & 0 & \mathbf{0}
\end{array}\right].
\end{align*}

Next, fix $k=2$ and repeat the process on $W_1$. Again transfer the $k$'th row and column and any entries containing $1$.
\begin{align*}
W_2=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & ?\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & ?
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \boxed{0} & \mathbf{0}\\
0 & 1 & \boxed{1}\\
1 & 0 & ?
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & \boxed{1}\\
1 & \boxed{0} & \mathbf{0}
\end{array}\right].
\end{align*}

Finally, fix $k=3$ to find the last entries.
\begin{align*}
W_3=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & ? & 0\\
? & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \mathbf{0} & \boxed{0}\\
? & 1 & 1\\
1 & \boxed{0} & 0
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0\\
\mathbf{1} & 1 & \boxed{1}\\
\boxed{1} & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right].
\end{align*}

This final matrix $W_3$ is the transitive closure.